# Change Value of String Based on Media Metadata

Tags: java, string, media-player, metadata, media

I have a simple media player and in one of the classes I need to retrieve the metadata of the media. Thus far, I have successfully extracted the metadata, however when I attempt to use the values, the Strings returned are blank.

```
String album = "", artist = "", title = "", year = "";
...
public void addListItems(final Pane layout, final Stage stage, final Scene scene) {
    String[] sList = s.split("\\\\");
        try {
            Media media = new Media(new File(s).toURI().toURL().toString());
            media.getMetadata().addListener(new MapChangeListener<String, Object>() {
            public void onChanged(Change<? extends String, ? extends Object> arg0) {
                handleMetadata(arg0.getKey(), arg0.getValueAdded());
            }
            });
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(album); //Here, album returns as ""
        final Button lab = new Button(album + "--" + sList[sList.length - 1]);
}
...
public void handleMetadata(String key, Object value) {
    if (key.equals("album")) {
        album = value.toString(); //Here album returns as value.toString() correctly
    } else if (key.equals("artist")) {
        artist = value.toString();
    } else if (key.equals("title")) {
        title = value.toString();
    } else if (key.equals("year")) {
        year = value.toString();
    }
    }
```

I have done research on this topic, but the results I viewed did not help my circumstance. I greatly appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Please answer my question?

Comment: Well, this is depressing. I'm desperate and having a conversation with myself it seems.